# Can't change the style of the SearchView suggestions in Android

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-styles

I need to change the `SearchView` suggestions style to the `AppCompat.Light` theme (i.e. gray text on a white background). But I retried a lot of variants and no one changed the `SearchView` suggestions style.
[image: Screenshot]

My layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:theme="@style/Widget.AppTheme.Toolbar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Styles:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBarTrans">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <style name="Widget.AppTheme.Toolbar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse"/>

</resources>
```

The app theme is `AppTheme`, the activity theme is `AppTheme.NoActionBarTrans`.
What am I doing wrong? I tried to declare `SearchView` style but it just ignores this style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can style dropdown programatically using this code

```
SearchView searchView = new SearchView(context);
LinearLayout linearLayout1 = (LinearLayout) searchView.getChildAt(0);
LinearLayout linearLayout2 = (LinearLayout) linearLayout1.getChildAt(2);
LinearLayout linearLayout3 = (LinearLayout) linearLayout2.getChildAt(1);
AutoCompleteTextView autoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) linearLayout3.getChildAt(0);
//Set the input text color
autoComplete.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
// set the hint text color
autoComplete.setHintTextColor(Color.WHITE);
//Some drawable (e.g. from xml)
autoComplete.setDropDownBackgroundResource(R.drawable.drop_down_bg);
```

Comment: Thank you! Although, I wanna know all same how to make it using styles.

Comment: that shows how impossible Android can get when the ThemeOverlay overrides any previously declared style